# home light switch problem

Tags: electrical, light

I'm having a bit of an issue. I've been doing electrical work for the past year or so but I'm still relatively new to this. Most of the stuff I have done has been a plug and play system or simple fixture lighting units on rather newer homes.

Recently I changed a light fixture in the home and it was wired good and well. I went to turn of the light at the switch and it just surged and audibly and visually sparked at the switch. Luckily I didn't shut it off with my hand rather a plastic screwdriver. After this occurred, the light fixture itself remained on and I proceeded to cut all the power and pull the switch off and the light fixture came back on and remained on even without a switch being in place.

I'm curious if this is bad switch problem or if it was a short due to another power supply running to the fixture and when flipping the switch I created a surge of power to the switch causing it to short any advice will help !

Comment: Pictures of the switch and wires in the box will help.  Do you know if this the only switch for the light, or is there another switch that also controls the light?

Comment: Was there a circuit breaker that tripped due to this sparking? You didn't mention a tripped breaker. My first instinct is that you've got two separate circuits tangled together with your wiring. And I count one period in your blob of words.

Comment: I will have to get updated pictures tomorrow. No breaker was tripped when this incident  occurred. it is the only light switch that controls these lights. That was also my first thought that, perhaps there is two separate circuits to the in the mess of wiring. The only way i know how to check for that would be to check the with a tester while the power is on and the unit is removed.

Comment: Sounds like something was secured, or insulated, less well than you thought and the vibration brought it into contact. If so, open it up and make sure all connections are tight, mo wire is exposed except at the screws, etc. Sometimes connections do come free.